# d3 path - split into 2 new paths

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am working with a Force-directed node chart using d3js. I would like to use marker-mid attribute on the paths but apparently there is a bug in FireFox and Safari so the markers fail to render. This bug seems to be limited to marker-mid, as marker-end and marker-start render just fine.

So unless someone shares a solution I am resorting to a work-around. 
My idea is to split the arc into 2 separate paths and use the marker-end attribute.

The following is the called in the Tick function

```
function linkArc(d) {
var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x +     "," + d.target.y;
}`
```

As I read it, linkArc is generates the points between the 2 nodes. How can I change this function to generate a path from start to mid point ? ( then in another call, from mid-point to end )

I am thinking of calling 2 functions instead of one

- linkArcA = PathA starts at the source node and ends at the mid point
- linkArcB = PathB starts at the mid point and ends at the target node

Otherwise I am open to any alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce a working solution which might be helpful for others trying to overcome this bug.

Basics Steps

- Create 2 paths for each node - pathA as first half path , path B as
  the second half path.
- Run linkArc for PathA. Creates the full curved path
- Iterate over all PathA and push their mid-points to an array
- Run linkArcStart creating paths from start to mid-points
- Run LinkArcEnd creating paths from mid-points to start

Here are the snippets of the code used

```
pathA = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter()
.append("path")

pathB = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter()
.append("path")

var mpts = [];

function tick() {
  pathA.attr("d", linkArc);

  pathA.attr("mpts",function(d,i){
    var p = d3.select(this).node()
    var pt = p.getPointAtLength(p.getTotalLength()/2)
    mpts[i] = [pt.x,pt.y];
  })

  pathA.attr("d", linkArcStart);
  pathB.attr("d",linkArcEnd)
 }

function linkArc(d) {
 var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x) ,
  dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
  dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
  pts = "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 "      + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y
 return pts;
}
function linkArcStart(d,i) {
  dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x) ,
  dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
  dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
  pts = "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + mpts[i][0]+ "," + mpts[i][1]
 return pts;
}
function linkArcEnd(d,i) {
  dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x) ,
  dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
  dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
  pts = "M" + + mpts[i][0]+ "," + mpts[i][1] + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x+ "," + d.target.y
  return pts;
}
```

Hope this helps others who are struggling to create marker-mid that render in all browsers (on Mac)